# Python Webdriver my script won't find the button inside the iFrame

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify if a button is present on a webpage after I have successfully logged in.  I am using Webdriver with Python.  The button is in an iFrame.
This is my first webdriver python program using the a page object model framework.  Not bad so far i think.

The program successfully logs in but it won't find the iFrame.
I need some help please.

I receive the following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\TestCore  01\LoginPage_TestCase.py", line 16, in test_login_valid_user
login_page.isAdministration_present()
File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\TestCore  01\page.py", line 44, in isAdministration_present
content_frame = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.contentFrame)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",  line 664, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",  line 175, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:  {"method":"id","selector":"testcore"}
```

My full code snipped it as follows:

```
    # This class is where all my locators will be defined
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class MainPageLocators(object):
    GO_BUTTON = (By.ID, 'submit')
    usernameTxtBox = (By.ID, 'unid')
    passwordTxtBox = (By.ID, 'pwid')
    submitButton = (By.ID, 'button')
    AdministrationButton = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.gwt-HTML.firepath-matching-node')
    AdministrationButtonXpath = (By.XPATH, '/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div')
    AdministrationButtonCSS = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div')
    contentFrame = (By.ID, 'testcore')


from element import BasePageElement
from locators import MainPageLocators

# This class is the base page class
class BasePage(object):

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver

# This class is the LoginPage.  All the methods for the login page are defined here
class LoginPage(BasePage):

def click_go_button(self):
    element = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.GO_BUTTON)
    element.click()

def userLogin_valid(self):
    userName_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.usernameTxtBox)
    userName_textbox.clear()
    userName_textbox.send_keys("user1")
    password_textbox =  self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.passwordTxtBox)
    password_textbox.clear()
    password_textbox.send_keys("Pass1")
    submitButton = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.submitButton)
    submitButton.click()

# Is the Administration button present on the dashboard page
def isAdministration_present(self):

    content_frame = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.contentFrame)
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(content_frame)
    administrationButtonCSS = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButtonCSS)



    # This class is the TestCase test class for the Login page where all the test cases is defined 
    import unittest
    from selenium import webdriver
    import page

    class LoginPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get("http://mypc:8080/testcore01")

def test_login_valid_user(self):
    login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
    login_page.userLogin_valid()
    login_page.isAdministration_present()
```

When i inspect the element in Firefox the HTML is as follows:

```
    <body style="margin: 0px;">
    <iframe id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="position: absolute; width: 0;   height: 0; border: 0;" tabindex="-1" src="javascript:''"/>
    <iframe id="testCore" src="javascript:''" style="position: absolute; width: 0px; height: 0px; border: medium none;" tabindex="-1"/>
   <div style="position: absolute; z-index: -32767; top: -20cm; width: 10cm; height: 10cm; visibility: hidden;" aria-hidden="true"/>
   <div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
   <div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
   <div class="gwt-HTML">Administration</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your selector.

```
contentFrame = (By.ID, 'testcore')
```

should be

```
contentFrame = (By.ID, 'testCore') # capital "C"
```

#### Why?

According to your HTML:

```
<iframe id="testCore"...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the typo and my test run goes further now.  It cannot evaluate the CSS selector now for the Administration button.    The error is:                                                                  InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector /body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/div is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

Comment: That's because that xpath selector is *terribly* ugly.... it is extremely brittle.  I cannot help you further unless you share HTML

Comment: The HTML is:    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; height: 30px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabs" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 16384px;">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab-selected" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTab GEGQEWXCK" style="background-color: rgb(254, 255, 238);">
<div class="gwt-TabLayoutPanelTabInner">
<div class="gwt-HTML">Administration</div>
</div>